# Why is the mini-map not showing?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

In *Assassins creed 3* it is so hard for me to find people when I have to press back all the time. Other people have a small map at the bottom of their screen, but I don't. I was wondering how do I get that map to display.

Comment: Could it be that the minimap is off-screen for you, because your screen  is misaligned?

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings, and then go to video settings there should be an option for turning the mini-map off or on.